# Read list from a text file js

Tags: javascript

Hello i'm trying to read this list from a file

this

```
 this.testJson = {
            list:[ 
                {src:"x1.jpg",title:"x1",song:"x1.mp3"},
                {src:"x2.jpg",title:"x2",song:"x2.mp3"},
                {src:"x3.jpg",title:"x3",song:"x3.mp3"},
                {src:"x4.jpg",title:"x4",song:"x4.mp3"}
              ]
            }
```

to

```
this.testJson = {
        list:[ 
            // read x.txt or x.txt from a URL
          ]
        }
```

and x.txt contain

```
    {src:"x1.jpg",title:"x1",song:"x1.mp3"},
    {src:"x2.jpg",title:"x2",song:"x2.mp3"},
    {src:"x3.jpg",title:"x3",song:"x3.mp3"},
    {src:"x4.jpg",title:"x4",song:"x4.mp3"}
```

as i do not have any java script experience , can somebody help me with this ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You have to expose that file from a web-server so your JavaScript can make an http request on that file.

To load resources from JavaScript you have to make an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) or better known as AJAX request.

Actually this requires some setup so using a library would be easier. My favourite one is [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios). It has a really simple API and handles response parse as well, so when you load axios on your web-site this is an approach you might follow :

```
axios.get('path-to-file').then(function(response){
    this.testJson.list = response.data
});
```

Note that your **x.txt** does not seem like a valid JSON. It has to be a valid one so axios can parse it. If you decide to parse the file on your own you have to use [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) API.

Comment: as i do not have any java script experience , can you explain how to do the exact for the example ? thanks !

Comment: im sorry , but i think i cant make it work ... can you show me the example using mine example x1 x2 x3 .... ?

Comment: Cannot set property 'list' of undefined